# Prefixing matching lines in a file

Tags: parsing, sed, awk, grep

I've tried doing this myself with the following:

```
for i in $(grep something toprefix.log); do sed -i -e 's/^/prefix/' $i; done
```

First of all, apologies for the bone-headedness - I know the above doesn't work!

Basically, I want to apply a prefix to matching lines in a log file using grep, and sed or awk.

```
prefix-matching
prefix-matching
not-matching
prefix-matching
not-matching
not-matching
prefix-matching
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sed -i '/something/s/^/prefix/' toprefix.log
```

**Edit:** For details see http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html

**Edit:** Removed '<' since '-i' is used.

**Edit:** Tabs are `\t`, so

```
$ sed -i '/something/s/^/prefix\t/' toprefix.log
```

adds `prefix` and a tab.

Comment: Thanks Tichodroma. I tried this and get 'sed: no input files'. Also, apologies - I failed to mention that the 'something' I was parsing with grep isn't at the start of the lines in toprefix.log.

Comment: Don't use input redirection '<'.

Comment: '/something/' looks for 'something' *anywhere* in a line.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the edit! Good job - works. You can probably tell I'm a bit new to sed syntax. ;)

Comment: Cheeky little addition if you'd oblige (if it's not straightforward, ignore)... If I wanted to put a tab in after the prefix, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: @rockshore: Not to mention an accept. I would upvote if I had more votes left today.

Comment: So let's wait until tomorrow :)

Comment: Sorry guys - also new to this site! Done the deed. :)

Answer (score 1):

In `awk`:

```
awk '/something/{print "prefix\t"$0;next}1' myfile > mynewfile
```

Comment: Don't you need a `next` after printing the prefixed line, so that it's not printed without the prefix too?